# Firebug shows image downloads twice

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, firebug

On a website I'm working I have this problem, the Firebug timeline on Firefox shows that every single image is downloaded twice, this happens when I refresh the page using Ctrl-F5.

Chrome Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) shows that images are downloaded once as expected.

Please help me understand what this happens and how to prevent images from downloading twice on Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "Firebug timeline"?

When I visit those 2 pages, Firebug's *Net* panel shows the first page fetching 4 images (once each), and the second page fetching 1 image (once) plus "random.png".

I cannot see any problem, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> or not.

The response codes on a plain refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) are *304*, and the cache seems to be working.

FF version: 3.6.13
Firebug Version: 1.6.2

Maybe there's a conflict with other add-ons and/or other Firebug plugins?

Comment: This is right, I was using YSlow set to automatically run tests, after disabling YSlow automatic test things now look normal... It looks like YSlow needs to re-download images to check some info needed for the test.